# Execute a javascript function from a file Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am testing a page using the IE browser driver and there is a JavaScript function that is called when clicking on a button.
The function is in a file called "app.js" from what I can see in the DOM.
I have tried:

```
private static JavascriptExecutor jsExec;
jsExec.executeScript("myFunction();");
```

but this always returns an error.

The properties of "app.js" point to: myhtml/app.js

How do I execute this function?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you call myFunction() from the browser's console?

Comment: Hi Linh, 
If I just try to run myFunction() by itself it comes back as "undefined", but if I run 'h t t p s://myhtml/app.js/myFuntion() then it runs

Comment: I guess the path to the file app.js which you mentioned you see in the DOM, is incorrect.
Maybe you can paste the DOM where the file app.js is called?

Comment: <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, we had some holidays last week. About your js function, I suspicious the path/directory of the file. And I can be sure that it's not Selenium issue. Once you can run the function in console, it will be run in Selenium. I cannot say exactly which issue it is, but maybe you can check the path of the js file? Btw, what is the page url?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `javascript` function in this way -

```
 JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 js.executeScript("myFunction();");
```

Comment: Hi Nerandra, The JavascripExecutor runs fine, it's just that the function is not executed. I believe it is due to not being in the actual html but in a separate .js file.